# If is not working in javascript-meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a piece of code on click event for set a session variable. The console log in working in event click, but it doesn't go inside if condition:

```
      'click .family': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('in change'); // result in change
        $("#btnFamily").html(event.target.text);

        var role = event.target.text;
        console.log('role',role); //result role  Fils

         if(role == "Fils"){
             console.log('here in son'); //never comes here
             Session.set('family', "Son");  //never comes here
         }

    },
```

Comment: result `role  Fils` - I see two spaces in your comment ... perhaps role is `" Fils"` rather than `"Fils"`

Comment: Did you just add an extra space to your console log comment, or is `role` actually equal to `' Fils'` (with a leading space)?

Comment: yes. it was for spaces ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Javascript then use role.trim()=='Fils' and if using jQuery then use $.trim(role)=='Fils'

you can use triple equal(===) operator for strict validation

i think this will be helpful..